# UserControl occasionally doesn't receive click messages

Tags: winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm writing a custom control with button like behavior. The user need to be able to handle the click event and the control needs to visually signal that it has been pressed. I change the visual state of the control in the OnMouseDown method and revert it back in OnMouseUp, and that works perfectly; however, I've noticed in testing that my control will not always receive mouse click messages, but the device is making the proper auditory signals for a click and the control isn't losing focus.

P.S. If anyone know of a good utility that will allow me to log windows messages sent to my app that would be swell and maybe help me see what may be going wrong.

Here what I have very simplified version of what I have

```
public class CustomButton : UserControl
{
    private bool _isMouseDown = false;//flag tells PaintBorder what state to draw

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnPaint(e);
         PaintBackground(e);
         PaintBorder(e, _isMouseDown);
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _isMouseDown = true;

            if (!this.Focused)
            {
                this.Focus();
            }
            else //getting focus causes Invalidate, no need to call twice
            {
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isMouseDown)
        {
            _isMouseDown = false;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code to show how you are creating the buttons as well as handle their actions. Without it, we can only guess what's really going on.

Comment: @NicholasPost: Code is up!

Comment: To see window messages you may use RemoteSpy (part of the remote tools coming with WM SDK): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894593.aspx. It works like the local VS Spy tool.

Comment: For spying and logging you may implement DrDobbs cespy to intercept Message API.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my button control for Compact Framework.

It turns out that if you click a button rapidly enough, some of the `Click`s will become `DoubleClick`s.

This code fixed the issue for me:

```
protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClick(e);
}
```

Beware that after inserting this code `DoubleClick` won't work anymore.